# Accesing HTML elements from Java

Tags: java, html, web

I´ve programmed some basic web applications using GWT. So all I´ve coded is just pure java (although the client part is transformed to javascript).

What I wanna know is how can I access and manipulate html elements (fields of a form, some text, etc) from server side using java (no GWT). 
I mean, a web application where I have some .html files and then I use some kind of framework from server side. Is that way of accesing html element framework dependent?  How could I manipulate those elements from a servlet, for example?

I know it´s a very general question, but I´d appreciate any help or tips, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, at first you might want to look at a basic [servlet tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html) and at a [JSP tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/). These are the first steps, no frameworks are involved here, but I think for the basic understanding of how it works you really should look through this information, and then only read about Spring or any other framework with a great MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

> What I wanna know is how can I access and manipulate html elements (fields of a form, some text, etc) from server side using java (no GWT).

The server side *creates* the HTML (possibly using data submitted through a form). At the lowest level, it's simply concatenating text. The various web application frameworks offer different ways to work at a more abstract level, i.e. via a template mechanism (JSP) and/or through component libraries that replace elements in a basic HTML layout with the actual data (JSF, Wicket).

However, once the HTML has been generated and sent to the client, it cannot be manipulated by the server, except through Javascript sent along with the HTML and executed by the browser. AJAX then allows it to connect back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Spring MVC Framework.